# Unexpected EOF issue tkinter python?

Tags: python, tkinter, eof

I'm about to finish creating a basic calculator in tkinter in python, but for some reason there is an unexpected EOF issue. For some reason the computer reached the end of the code without executing all of it. I have no idea why, the code is below:

```
from tkinter import *
e = Tk(className="Krishna's Calculator")
e.geometry("460x614")
e.resizable(0,0)

def insert(value):
    var.set(var.get() + value)
    eval(var)
def button(text, width, font, highlightbackground, x, y):
    tkinter_button = Button(e, text=text, width=width, command=lambda: insert(text), font=font, highlightbackground=highlightbackground)
    tkinter_button.place(x=x, y=y)
def clear():
    var.set(" ") 
def equals(vare):
    var.set(eval(vare))
helvetica = "Helvetica 50"
arial = "Arial 50 bold"
var = StringVar()
label = Label(e, textvariable = var,bd=5,width=16, relief = SOLID, font = "Arial 50 ",bg="white", fg="black",activebackground="#bb99ff", height = 5,pady = 3)
label.place(x=0,y=0)
button(text = "÷", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 301)
button(text = "×", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 364)
button(text = "-", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 426)
button(text = "+", width=4, font = helvetica, highlightbackground='#8533ff', x = 344, y = 488)
equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=4, command = equals(var.get()), font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#8533ff')
equal.place(x = 344, y = 551)
aclear = Button(e, text = "AC",width=8, command = clear, font = "Helvetica 50",highlightbackground='#737373')
aclear.place(x = 0, y = 302)
button(text = "%", width=4, font = helvetica,highlightbackground='#737373', x = 228, y = 302)
button(text = ".", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 550)
button(text = "0", width = 8, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 550)
button(text = "1", width =4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 488)
button(text = "2", width =4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 488)
button(text = "3", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 488)
button(text = "4", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 426)
button(text = "5", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 426)
button(text = "6", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 426)
button(text = "7", width=4, font = arial ,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 0, y = 364)
button(text = "8", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 114, y = 364)
button(text = "9", width=4, font = arial,highlightbackground='#ffffff', x = 228, y = 364)
e.mainloop()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, tysm!

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in `eval(var)` -- the value doesn't have balanced brackets.

Comment: `command = equals(var.get()` should be `command = lambda: equals(var.get()`

Comment: now this error message appears:
File "/Users/parthagarwal/Desktop/PythonCourse/calcwer.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    tkinter_button = Button(e, text=text, width=width, command=lambda: insert(text), font=font, highlightbackground=highlightbackground)
  File "/Users/parthagarwal/Desktop/PythonCourse/calcwer.py", line 8, in insert
    eval(str(var))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'PY_VAR0' is not defined

Comment: I don't see `eval(str(var))` anywhere in your code.

Comment: it is there in line 8.

Comment: That's `eval(var)` not `eval(str(val))`. But it probably should be `eval(var.get())`

Comment: You are creating a lot of identical widgets the hard way. You could get rid of almost half of your code if you created them in a loop. For instance your operator buttons are all identical except for the text. You could just make one button and loop over it with this, `for sym in ('*','+','-','÷'):`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining the command line:

```
equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=4, command = equals(var.get()), font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#8533ff')
```

The value inside the "equals()" parameter needs to be a string such as:

```
equal = Button(e, text = "=",width=4, command = equals('var.get()'), font = "Helvetica 50", highlightbackground='#8533ff')
```

Give that a try.